# How many mysql connection being utilized when accessing same web page by multiple users

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, database-connection

I have a sample web page created using PHP and what it does is connecting to MySQL to fetch records from a table. Following are my questions.

1. If two users(two browsers) access this same web page at the same time, does it create two MySQL connections to communicate with MySQL server or does it reuse the firstly created connection for the other concurrent access?
2. By default `max_connections` value in Mysql is 151 so if 200 concurrent requests made for this page does that means requests after first 151 will get "Too many connections" error from MySQL connection.
3. If I want to support 1000 concurrent requests for the web page is it safe to increase the `max_connections` value to 1000. What would be the implications?

Following is my code

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";

$conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();
```

Comment: It might depend a bit if your server is able to pool connections or not. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.pooling.php . If you increase the max connections the most obvious tradeoff is going to be performance. So it depends if you think your hardware can cope.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the reply. Do you know whether it creates mysql connection per request if I don't use pool connections?

Comment: I'm not 100% expert but I would expect that it would have to, yes.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the info.